# Running apt-get on EC2 without coughing up for a bunch of bandwidth charges

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt-get

I'm running Ubuntu on EC2 (using the alestic community AMI) and on startup my new instances use up a bunch of bandwidth running apt-get upgrade etc. Bandwidth between EC2 instances is free... anyone know if there's a mirror of the Ubuntu packages somewhere on EC2 I can use instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an official one but Right Scale have offered up a repository for other users of ec2:

http://www.rightscale.com/

**ec2-hardy-sources.list**

```
deb http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu hardy main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

**ec2-intrepid-sources.list**

```
deb http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu intrepid main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu intrepid-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu intrepid-security main restricted universe multiverse **strong text**
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Hardy, Intrepid, and (soon) Jaunty images published on Alestic.com already use Ubuntu archive mirrors internally on EC2.